# Montel's Theorem WLOG statement: why the domain can be assumed to be the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help understanding the WLOG statement in a text I am working through. Here is the theorem as stated up until the statement that I am confused by:

**Theorem (Montel's Theorem):** A family $\mathcal{F}$ of meromorphic functions on a domain $D$ that omits three values is normal.

Since normality is a local property, we can assume that the domain $D$ is the open unit disk $\lbrace |z|<1 \rbrace$. (rest of the proof)

Comment: How can we take any arbitrary domain (with holes in it potentially) and move everything to the unit disk WLOG? I am missing something serious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property $P$ is called *local* if the following is true:

> if every point of a domain has a neighborhood in which $P$ holds, then $P$ holds in the domain.

Normality is such a property. So, we only need to prove that for each point $z\in D$ there is a disk centered at $z$ on which normality holds. Pick any such disk. A linear change of variable moves it to the unit disk. Now we are in the "WLOG" setup: a family of functions is defined on the unit disk, and omits three values there.

Comment: Ahh, and then this explains my second question, "Why, WLOG, are these new functions analytic?"

By the same reasoning, we choose $z\in D$ away from poles (which is possible). The functions are analytic there. Is this correct?

Comment: No, I don't think you can avoid the poles of $f$. For every point $z\in D$ we need a neighborhood in which the family is normal. If $z$ happens to be a pole of some members of the family, there is no way around this issue. So, when working on the unit disk, we still have meromorphic functions, with a possibility of them having poles.

Comment: Alright. I don't mean to keep you, but I think I am close to understanding the first few sentences of this theorem! So, after it is established that the domain of $f\in\mathcal{F}$ is the unit disk, we compose the functions with FLT to move the omitted values to 0,1, and $\infty$. From here the author says, "Since the functions in $\mathcal{F}$ are then analytic and nonzero on the unit disk, they have analytic roots of all orders". I follow the analytic roots bit, but what about the omitted values being 0,1 and $\infty$ ensures that these new functions are analytic on the unit disk?

Comment: Because $\infty$ is omitted. This means no poles.

Comment: This should have been obvious to me! Thank you for your time.